# .NET Upgrade Assistant: How does an incremental upgrade connect the .NET library to its corresponding Framework library?

Tags: .net, upgrade

I created a simple Framework (4.6.2) library with a single class to test the .NET Upgrade assistant.  I chose the **Side-by-side incremental project** upgrade.  When it created the new .NET library, I could not see any files that connected the .NET library with the original Framework library.  This upgrade supposedly "establishes a link between current and target projects." Where is this link located?  How are these two libraries linked together?  I expected that this upgrade type would allow me to reference the upgraded .NET library from another .NET library and have access to classes in the Framework library through the upgraded .NET library, but I was not able to do this in my test solution.  Is this upgrade type useful for class libraries, and, if so, what benefit does it provide when upgrading class libraries?